# H2 database console on Railo

Tags: macos, coldfusion, h2, railo

I know that H2 is included in Railo, but where is the H2 database console on Railo?

I am trying to get to web based gui on it. Does it have to be downloaded separately?

Comment: If it is a gui front end, you almost certainly have to [install it separately](http://h2database.com/html/quickstart.html). AFAIK, like ACF, Railo only includes the minimum components necessary for jdbc connectivity ie the driver. Typically if you want to interact a database outside of CF (via an gui or ide) you have to install the tools yourself.

Comment: Hm.. I might be wrong about that. I found [this post](http://po.chassay.net/blog/post.cfm/how-to-start-railo-from-with-a-cd-and-a-h2-database) which suggests you might be able to access it by double clicking the `h2.jar`. (Unfortunately I had already run the h2 windows installer, so I cannot verify it works with a plain Railo install - nothing extra).

Comment: After diving more into it, it seems that there is a whole set of files that run the gui, and they are not present in the Railo installation. I tried the double click trick and it does not work. I also tried copying in the `h2.sh` file that is not enough either. Basically, your first comment was spot on. It has to be be downloaded separately.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. Despite uninstalling the program on my machine double clicking the jar worked for me. But I suspected I was not getting accurate results, since I was too lazy to restart. Thanks for the confirm.

Comment: You should put that answer

Comment: As far as I know, all the files that are needed to run the H2 Console are included in the `h2.jar` file. However, I don't know Railo so I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: @ThomasMueller - Thanks for chiming in. So ignoring Railo for the moment, assuming we have the full jar - how would you normally do it? James - You are referring to [this console](http://h2database.com/html/quickstart.html), correct?

Comment: @Leigh - Yes, that console

Comment: @JamesMohler - Well I defer to Thomas' advice on this one :) But I will say I was still able to access the console after a restart. I ran the h2 jar from a command prompt (in windows), and the URL opened up just like described in the docs. {shrug} :)

Comment: I am on a macos, so maybe that had something to do with it

Comment: @JamesMohler  What did you try?

Comment: @JamesMohler - I do not that is the "right" way, but I was able to access an H2 database from both Railo and the web console under windows using server mode. 1) I created an "Other" datasource `class = org.h2.Driver, connection string=jdbc:h2:c:\path\to\myDatabaseName;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;` 2) Started the console from a command prompt: `java -jar C:\path\to\railo-express-4.0.4.001-nojre\lib\ext\h2.jar` . Then used the same connection settings for the "JDBC URL", "username" and "password".

Comment: How would that be done on macos?

Comment: No idea :) I am not running macos, but I imagine it has something similar that allows you to run a jar via `java -jar ...`